# (ReactJS,Babel,Webpack,NodeJS) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have been killing myself over this to work for days, but to no avail.
I am using ReactJS and Babel. I have node JS installed as well as webpack.
It is a simple Hello World app.
The error I get is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Here is the source code:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webapp.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './webapp.js',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**webapp.js**

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('static'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Started server at port", port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello React!</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Is there any thing else in error that you have cite or nothin more?

Comment: Try babel-loader instead of babel

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it will just append automatically the `-loader` if you omit it

Comment: @Aperçu that was in webpack 1. From webpack 2 nee to configure that manually.

Comment: There is still a fallback

Comment: I just reproduce your sources and have no error.  (I have done fixes concerning adoptation to webpack 2 and add "target": "node" to webpack)

Answer (score 0):

Your webpack is configured to build `webapp.js` source. This is server side node applications. So add this:

```
target: "node"
```

to your webpack config.
This option enable `node` build environment.

In order to build client application you need another configuration.
The webpack config must have

```
target: "web"
entry: './App.js',
```

And your html must have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="App.js">
```

Because browser can not understand modern syntax. And you need to build and load compiled js bundle.

Comment: Tried both the approaches mentioned. 1) Adding target: 'node' 2) changing babel to babel-loader. Still shows me the error. Is there some simple thing I am missing? Is it correct to call "App.js" as text/javascript from my index.html?

Comment: You does not clarify your error and line of code where error fired up. Also where you have see it. Seems you have error in browser so I write update.

Comment: Ok well, i used my babel compiled JS in the script tag as well. It throws up this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at App-compiled.js:3"

Comment: unfortunately, its still not working for me. but thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what oklas mentioned,

I noticed that you have:

```
 test: /\.js$/,
```

instead you should have:

```
test: /\.jsx?/,
```

(because the react preset is looking for jsx in order to transpile it to js)

If after that change you still have issues, I'd recommend npm i -D the latest babel presets, as follows:

```
 module.exports = {
 mode: 'development',
 target: 'web',
 entry: `${SRC_DIR}\\app.jsx`,
 output: {
    filename: CHANGE_ME,
    path: DIST_DIR
    },  
 module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
           presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
           }
       },
```